# Failed to start spring boot integration test when setting the application type as reactive

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-webflux

I have an application using Spring Webflux via Spring boot 2.0.0.M3.

The application is set as **REACTIVE** type when running it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(AgentApplication.class);
    application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
    application.run(args);
}
```

The reactive app works fine if running the main application. But I failed to start this app in my spring boot integration test.

I declared the test as below,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    properties = {"spring.main.webApplicationType=reactive"})
@ActiveProfiles("integTest")
public class NoteHandlerTest {

@Autowired
private WebTestClient webClient;

@Test
public void testGetNoteNotFound() throws Exception {
    this.webClient.get().uri("/note/request/{id}", "nosuchid").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .exchange().expectStatus().isOk();
}

}
```

I got below error when running the test case,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
>   Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start ReactiveWebApplicationContext due to missing
>   ReactiveWebServerFactory bean.    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:49)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:349)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>     ... 25 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: **Unable to
>   start ReactiveWebApplicationContext due to missing
>   ReactiveWebServerFactory bean.**  at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:61)
>     ... 44 more

Does it have any configuration issue to run spring boot integration test with webflux?

You can access the complete demo project from [here](https://github.com/zxkane/spring-boot-webflux-router-issue/tree/spring-boot-test-reactive).

Comment: I'm hitting this bug too. Have you made any progress?

Comment: It turned out it's caused by the dependencies of `spring cloud`, which still works on the integration with spring 5. see [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10017) for detail.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I ended up just not using @SpringBootTest at all, because I had to also wire up other stuff during startup anyway.

Comment: Please include all the JARS and versions you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't it just a typo in your configuration property?

`"spring.main.web-application-type=reactive"`

Comment: You saved my evening, my good sir. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had this exception too when using

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

instead of

```
@SpringBootTest()
```